# Type hints and pandas if one considers indexing columns as part of the type

Tags: python-3.x, types

Conceptually the indexing and column names of a pandas data frame seem to me equivalent to its data type. Is there a sensible way to portray this using type hints or is this a matter for docstrings?

Comment: Given pandas code is constantly adding and dropping columns, maybe a type alias based on the index would be most useful, though the columns are essential to the interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used 'seem to me' because it's a matter of opinion. One could consider a data frame's type as akin to a table schema in SQL. But a data frame has a constantly mutating schema, hence my problem. If one uses a type hint of 'DataFrame', that's unhelpful - as a minimum it's handy to know the set of columns which uniquely define a row and perhaps the columns a function uses. What's a good way to document them?

Comment: @Charliemops Care to elaborate? The question seems precise enough to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this library: https://pypi.org/project/dataenforce/

Doesn't seem to support anything with respect to names and dtypes of index columns.

I haven't used it, but it looks interesting.

Comment: That should be worth investigating. Thanks.